# VPN Service setHttpProxy with Pac URI

Tags: android, proxy, vpn, pac, android-vpn-service

According to Android docs, the [VpnService.Builder.setHttpProxy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder#setHttpProxy(android.net.ProxyInfo)) method has been added in API level 29. Which is fine. 
But the setHttpProxy method needs and object for [ProxyInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/ProxyInfo) class, which is deprecated in API level 22.

Now I need to use the [buildPacProxy](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/ProxyInfo#buildPacProxy(android.net.Uri)) method of the ProxyInfo class, which isn't working for me.

Can anyone please help me set a PAC URI to the VPN service by any alternate way? My end goal is to apply a PAC Uri to the device, which will monitor all the device traffic. I was thinking of using a VPN to apply the PAC Uri, bu creating a fake VPN, which does not connect to any server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the first part of your question, `android.net.ProxyInfo` is currently not actually marked deprecated (see [the source file in the master branch](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/net/ProxyInfo.java)). In fact, it was "undeprecated" in 2015, see [this commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/f361e3dff9bb3d8ed72a76d5703761140296bbd0).

So this looks just like an error in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ProxyInfo).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I am more concerned about how can I set the PAC uri to the device level. I tried setting pac to vpn and it worked on emulator, although, the same code did not work on the actual device (I have been using android 10 device).